# NoneType object is not iterable in python, I am avoiding the common mistakes like using assignment operator

Tags: python, nonetype

This is my code and I keep getting a NoneType object is not iterable error on the second last line.

```
for key, value in termdic.items():
#     value = List of lists where 1st entry is a documentID and the second is a position
    i=0
    temp = []

    for v in value:
#         print(v)
        current_doc = v[0]
        if i==0:
            prev_doc = v[0]
            i+=1
        if (prev_doc == current_doc):
                temp.append(v[1])
        if (prev_doc != current_doc):
            if key not in term_position_dic:
#                 initialize
                term_position_dic[key] = [[prev_doc,len(temp),temp]]
#                 encode(temp)
#                 delta_position_dic[key] = [[prev_doc,len(temp),temp]]
            else:
                term_position_dic[key].append([prev_doc,len(temp),temp])
#                 encode(temp)
#                 delta_position_dic[key].append([prev_doc,len(temp),temp])
#           We are in the reset phase
            prev_doc= current_doc
            temp = [v[1]]
```

Note: Termdic is a dic of key= term and value = list of lists which = [[docID, number of occurrences, [list of the positions of the word in the document.]

```
uncompressed_dic = {}
for k, value in term_position_dic.items():
    temparray = []
    for v in value:
        docID = v[0]
        count = v[1]
        poslist = v[2]
        tarray = [docID, count].extend(poslist)
        temparray.extend(tarray)
    uncompressed_dic[k] = temparray
```

Also, why would docID, count, posList be None after iteration, it shows as it is when I print it but when the final array is build all values are None.

Comment: It's best to add enough code so that someone else would be able to copy paste it and get the same error. If we can't create the error, we can't point out what's wrong. What is `term_position_dic` equal to when it's causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't mean the third to last line? `poslist` is probably the NoneType, which just means its equal to None. Try `print(poslist)` before `[docID, count].extend` and see if it's actually equal to `None`. If it is, then print `value` to see what's wrong with that `value`.

You haven't shared the code that generates the `term_position_dic` object, so I can't help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

`list.extend` doesn't return a copy of the list. It returns a `None`, so you're doing `None.extend`, and `None` isn't an iterable with an `extend` method. Instead of:

```
tarray = [docID, count].extend(poslist)
```

Which results in `tarray == None`, which you can't `extend`, do this:

```
tarray = [docID, count]
if poslist: 
    tarray.extend(poslist)
temparray.extend(tarray)
```